# Modify object attribute/property — without creating custom function

Tags: oracle, object, oop, attributes, oracle-spatial

I have an Oracle 18c [SDO_GEOMETRY object](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-object-type.htm#SPATL489) that has attributes (aka properties):

```
with cte as (
select 
    sdo_util.from_wktgeometry('MULTILINESTRING ((0 5 0, 10 10 10, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 -10000))') shape
from dual)

select 
    a.shape.sdo_gtype as old_gtype,
    a.shape.sdo_gtype + 300 as new_gtype,
    a.shape
from 
    cte a


OLD_GTYPE  NEW_GTYPE    SHAPE 
---------  ---------    -----
     3006       3306    SDO_GEOMETRY(3006, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1, 10, 2, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(0, 5, 0, 10, 10, 10, 30, 0, 33.54, 50, 10, 33.54, 60, 10, -10000))
```

I want to modify the GTYPE attribute of the SDO_GEOMETRY object:

- Old GTYPE: 3006
- New GTYPE: 3306

---

It's possible to modify the GTYPE attribute using a custom function  (or an inline function):

- See @AlbertGodfrind's answer in [Convert M-enabled SDE.ST_GEOMETRY to SDO_GEOMETRY using SQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/428825/62572)

However, as an experiment, I want to modify the GTYPE attribute right in the SELECT clause in a query -- without using a custom function.

For example, I wonder if there might be OOTB functionality like this:

```
modify_object_property(object, property_name, new_val) returns sdo_geometry
```

---

Is there a way to modify an SDO_GEOMETRY GTYPE attribute/property — without creating a custom function?

Related: [Replace value in SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY varray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547985/replace-value-in-sdo-elem-info-array-varray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sdo_geometry constructor as follows

```
    with cte as (
    select 
        sdo_util.from_wktgeometry('MULTILINESTRING ((0 5 0, 10 10 10, 30 0 33.54),(50 10 33.54, 60 10 -10000))') shape
    from dual)
    select sdo_geometry(a.shape.sdo_gtype + 300,
                        a.shape.sdo_srid,
                        a.shape.sdo_point,
                        a.shape.sdo_elem_info,
                        a.shape.sdo_ordinates) as shape
      from cte a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the contents of an object in SQL. You just need to make sure you use an **alias** on the table. For example:

```
update my_table t
set t.geom.sdo_gtype = t.geom.sdo_gtype + 300
where ... ;
```

But that is not what you are looking for. Modifying an object that way in the select list is not possible. Hence the approach via a custom function.