# Replace value in SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY varray

Tags: oracle, oracle18c, oracle-spatial, varray

I have an existing SDO_GEOMETRY in Oracle 18c:

```
sdo_geometry(2003, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 1),
    sdo_ordinate_array(665287.423,4857578.086,   676832.320,4878119.585))
```

In the `sdo_elem_info_array` varray, I want to replace the final 1 with a 3:

- Before: (1, 1003, **1**)
- After: (1, 1003, **3**)

---

How can I replace that value in the `sdo_elem_info_array` varray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a user-defined function and edit it using PL/SQL:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION edit_info(i_geom SDO_GEOMETRY) RETURN SDO_GEOMETRY
IS
  v_geom SDO_GEOMETRY := i_geom;
BEGIN
  v_geom.SDO_ELEM_INFO(3) := 3;
  RETURN v_geom;
END;
SELECT edit_info(
         sdo_geometry(
           2003,
           null,
           null,
           sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 1),
           sdo_ordinate_array(665287.423, 4857578.086, 676832.320, 4878119.585)
         )
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=57d092cf6695c38438b92924aedeb074)*

Comment: I want to learn more about this part: `v_geom.SDO_ELEM_INFO(3) := 3;`. Do you know if it's usually just called *"modifying a varray element"*, or does it have any other names/formal names?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @MTO's solution, I suppose I could do it in a query too (without the need for a custom function):

```
with cte as (
select sdo_geometry(2003, 26917, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(665287.423, 4857578.086, 676832.320, 4878119.585)) shape
from   dual)

select sdo_geometry(a.shape.sdo_gtype,
                    a.shape.sdo_srid,
                    a.shape.sdo_point,
                    sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 3),
                    a.shape.sdo_ordinates) as shape
from cte a;

Result:
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 26917, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 3), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(665287.423, 4857578.086, 676832.32, 4878119.585))
```

Related:

- [Techniques for selecting an object's attribute](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4498503/techniques-for-selecting-an-objects-attribute#latest:%7E:text=surround%20the%20object%20name%20in%20braces)
- [Get object's attribute](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-enterprise-questions/get-st-geometry-object-s-attribute/m-p/1174306)
- [Modify object attribute/property — without creating custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71876147/modify-object-attribute-property-without-creating-custom-function)

Comment: This overwrites the entire `SDO_ELEM_INFO` varray with a new array rather than just modifying the 3rd element of the array (however, its much more complicated to just replace the 3rd element and keep everything else in SQL [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=78bdd45a09e1ab6808da9299dd1b7e45)).